# ggplot gives error that column is not found in the dataframe, when it exists

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running the following ggplot code:

```
mu <- ddply(dfcards, "cluster", summarise, grp.mean=mean(CardsBalance))  # Calculate means

  ggplot(dfcards[dfcards$cluster==1,], aes(x=CardsBalance, color = qrtClusIncome, 
                                           fill= qrtClusIncome)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity", alpha=0.9, bins = 200)+
    geom_density(alpha=0.6, size = 2)+
    geom_vline(data=mu, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color= qrtClusIncome ),
               linetype="dashed", size = 1.5)+
    labs(title="Distribution of Credit Cards Balance per Income quintile in Cluster 1",x="Cards Balance", 
         y = "Density")
```

and I am getting the error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'qrtClusIncome' not found
```

As you can see the 'qrtClusIncome' is a factor Column (3d from the end) in the dataframe that inputs the data to the ggplot function:

```
> str(dfcards[dfcards$cluster==1,])
'data.frame':   11200 obs. of  55 variables:
 $ cluster           : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Collateral        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TotalCredit       : num  575.9 982.5 85 5970.4 47.6 ...
 $ TotalCScore       : num  693 677 673 723 699 680 680 678 699 692 ...
 $ CarBalance        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CardsBalance      : num  575.9 982.5 85 0 47.6 ...
 $ ConsumerBalance   : num  0 0 0 5970 0 ...
 $ MortgageBalance   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Gender            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Age               : num  37 39 36 35 27 35 37 32 33 31 ...
 $ Profession        : chr  "Missing" "Bank Employee" "Bank Employee" "Missing" ...
 $ Lifetime          : num  5 8 10 7 7 10 12 6 10 8 ...
 $ Owner             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Income            : num  1e+06 1e+06 1e+06 1e+05 1e+05 ...
 $ viotiko           : num  8 0 0 8 6 8 8 8 0 7 ...
 $ pd_1year          : num  0.00843 0.00843 0.00843 0.00843 0.00843 ...
 $ pd_1year_group    : chr  "<1%" "<1%" "<1%" "<1%" ...
 $ viot_0            : num  0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ viot_1            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ viot_2            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ viot_3            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ viot_4            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ viot_5            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ viot_6            : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ viot_7            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ viot_8            : num  1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ Bank_Employee     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Businessman       : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Doctor            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Engineer          : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Farmer            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Housewife         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Independent       : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Lawyer            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Missing           : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ Pensioner         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PrSec_Employee    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PubSec_Employee   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Self_Employed     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Student           : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tradesman         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Unemployed        : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ OtherProf         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ qrtCollateral     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ qrtTotalCScore    : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 8 3 1 10 9 4 4 3 9 8 ...
 $ qrtCarBalance     : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ qrtCardsBalance   : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 7 8 5 2 4 7 7 7 4 5 ...
 $ qrtConsumerBalance: Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ qrtMortgageBalance: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ qrtAge            : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ qrtLifetime       : Factor w/ 9 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 3 4 3 3 4 5 2 4 3 ...
 $ qrtIncome         : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ qrtClusIncome     : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 2 ...
 $ MaxBalance        : num  39508 39508 39508 39508 39508 ...
 $ IncrCardsBal      : num  38932 38526 39423 39508 39461 ..
```

When I use a different variable -- i.e. 'as.factor(cluster)'-- the code works without a problem.

How do you explain this?  What should I change in my code?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: would you add the `dfcards` data to try the code on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is in your data frame `mu`. It looks like the error is probably in the line

```
geom_vline(data=mu, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color= qrtClusIncome ),
           linetype="dashed", size = 1.5)
```

From what I can see of your code `mu` doesn't contain `qrtClusIncome` and so the above line will error.